# style.css not loading in django html template

Tags: python, html, css, django, static

I created a login page and calling a static css sheet for styling but its not working.
I load static in my login.html and use

```
<html>
    
<head>
<title>PWC Login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css'%}">

</head>

<body> 
    <div class="loginbox">
        <img src="{% static 'images/avatar.png' %}" class="avatar">
            <h1 class="h1">Login Here</h1>
            <form>
                <p>Username</p>
                <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Enter Username">
                <p>Password</p>
                <input type="password" name="" placeholder="Enter Password">
                <input type="submit" name="" value="Login">
                <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a><br>
                <a href="#">Don't have an account?</a>
            </form>
    </div>
</body>   

</html>
```

**css**:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: url('static/images/pic1.jpeg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

.loginbox{
    width:320px;
    height:420px;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 70px 30px;
}

.avatar{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -50px;
    left: calc(50% - 50px);
}
```

i tried the html and css file separately and it works fine. the background is the jpeg file and the login box is centered. it has to be something in django but not sure what it is.

Comment: What do you mean "i tried the html and css file separately and it works fine."? That seems to contradict the problem you're asking about. Also, are there any 404s in the network tab?

Comment: sorry, allow me to clarify. i tried the html + css on its own (not in django) and it worked. its when i moved the html code to django template aand the css to a static css folder that i lose the styling.

Comment: First, make sure you have `{% load static %}` at the top of your HTML template.  Second, it would help to see your folder structure.  You should have a folder called **static** inside your app's folder, with a folder called **app_name** (whatever your app's name is, that is) then within *that* a folder called **css**, and finally within *that* folder your file, **style.css**.

Comment: so after all that, it turned out to be my cache in my browser. The only thing I need to fix now is the the background is repeating which is just a css issue. Appreciate the input

Answer (score 0):

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/"),
)
```